# Add Enrich.WithProperty to serilog global logger after initial configuration

Tags: .net, logging, serilog

We have a service with a Main() method that initializes our serilog logger like this:

```
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .MinimumLevel.Debug()
               .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
               .WriteTo.Seq(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SeqServer"], apiKey: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SeqApiKey"])
               .Enrich.WithProperty("ServiceName", "SomeConsumer")                   
               .CreateLogger();
```

Now, in a different method, I want to attach an additional Property to this logger. I want to add an .Enrich.WithProperty, because I like the logging style of 
`Log.Error("Somelog")`

How can I do that? I just want to attach a new property with some string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the method `CreateLogger` you cannot modify the logger instance created. If a specific method or class wants to enrich the log with more variables only in that particular context, then the `ForContext` is the way to go.

An alternative would be to create a dynamic custom enricher that you setup in the beginning, but that will change its behavior depending on some logic.

**Update 2021-08-21**: You can now use [Serilog.Enrichers.GlobalLogContext](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-enrichers-globallogcontext) to include global properties after the Serilog pipeline has been created.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out, and I suppose it will do:

```
SomeMethod() {
    var log = Log.Logger.ForContext("PropertyName", "Some string I need so bad");
    log.Debug("Beginning of log with enrichment");

}
```

This way I can avoid the `using` block, but I'm still curious if there is a way to modify the global Log.Logger object

Comment: That is the right way to do what you need with Serilog. You can create loggers from existing loggers, adding context variables (one or more).

Comment: this shows me this log `[19:58:05 INF] ( ) Beginning of log with enrichment`. In which part I can see the **PropertyName** value?

Comment: @JRichardsz I know this is late - but for others. Console & file loggers won't show the additional content by default, they're included in elastic /seq logs etc.