# Adding custom properties for all telemetry log type in Application Insights metrics

Tags: azure-application-insights

I d'like to add custom properties to metrics taken by Application Insights to each type of telemetry log of my app.
Which is

1. Custom Event
2. Request
   3.Exception
3. Trace
4. Page View
5. Dependency

Want to map Evn name for each and every activity which is logged in the Application Insights

To help out and filter logs no the basis of Env tag for ex QA, UAT and Prod

Am is to log all the environment log into single AI instance and use them and query filtering via log

Using `.Enrich.WithProperty(env, 'QA')` property did not workout for all type of log events.

Comment: [Application Insights API for custom events and metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Enrich.WithProperty to serilog global logger after initial configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215215/add-enrich-withproperty-to-serilog-global-logger-after-initial-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

*Below is the Sample code for adding custom events in Telemetry event.*

```cs
 var request = new RequestTelemetry();
 var client = new TelemetryClient();
 request.Name = "My Request";
 client.TrackRequest(request);
```

*For cmplete information you can refer this [So](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31056012) thread which has related discussions.*

*Also, as suggested by   [DeepDave-MT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15969115/deepdave-mt) even this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics) will also help.*